# Queries can't be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

After migrating to .NET 6 I am receiving following errors.

```
            var subsQuery = context.SubscriptionUsers
                .Where(x => subscritpionIds.Contains(x.SubscriptionId));

            var subscriptionUsers = await context.Users
                .Include(x => x.UserSettings)
                .Join(subsQuery, u => u.Id, su => su.UserId, (u, su) => new { su.SubscriptionId, User = u })
                .GroupBy(x => x.SubscriptionId)
                .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(x => x.User).ToList());
```

This code throws:

The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I can't understand why it throws error, but hiding "GroupBy" part - solves it. My solution is this:

```
var subscriptionUsers = (await context.Users
                    .Include(x => x.UserSettings)
                    .Join(subsQuery, u => u.Id, su => su.UserId, (u, su) => new { su.SubscriptionId, User = u })
                    .ToListAsync())
                    .GroupBy(x => x.SubscriptionId)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(x => x.User).ToList());
```

And I have another place, where I get same but different error:

```
var subscriptionsToSendTo = await context.Subscriptions
                .Join(context.PricingPlans.Where(x => x.SystemName == "PromoOneUsd"), sub => sub.PricingPlanId, pp => pp.Id, (sub, pp) => sub)
                .Include(x => x.SubscriptionUsers)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.User)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.UserSettings)
                .Where(x =>
                    (x.EndDate < daysRangeFromNow && x.EndDate > DateTime.UtcNow) &&
                    (x.SubscriptionUsers.FirstOrDefault()
                        .User.UserSettings.FirstOrDefault(us =>
                            us.Name.Equals("ReceivedSevenDaysBeforeNinetyNineCentOfferExpires")
                            && us.Value.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) == null
                    )
                ).ToListAsync();
```

Which throws:

The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of the 'string.Equals' overload with a 'StringComparison' parameter is not supported. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2129535 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I fixed this with:

```
        var subscriptionsToSendTo = await context.Subscriptions
            .Join(context.PricingPlans.Where(x => x.SystemName == "PromoOneUsd"), sub => sub.PricingPlanId, pp => pp.Id, (sub, pp) => sub)
            .Include(x => x.SubscriptionUsers)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.User)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.UserSettings)
            .Where(x =>
                (x.EndDate < daysRangeFromNow && x.EndDate > DateTime.UtcNow) &&
                (x.SubscriptionUsers.FirstOrDefault()
                    .User.UserSettings.FirstOrDefault(us =>
                        us.Name.ToLower() == "receivedsevendaysbeforeninetyninecentofferexpires"
                        && us.Value.ToLower() == "true") == null
                )
            ).ToListAsync();
```

**So I have questions:**

1. Why first part throws exception?
2. Are my solutions alright? Any better solutions?

Regards

Comment: Migrating from what? From EF 6?

Comment: 1) because there is no direct translation for `GroupBy` and get grouped items. Better to do client side grouping - it is much effective than old EF query which works. 2) Your solutions are good, but check that that you really need `ToLower()`, by default SQL Server has case insensitive collation.